# Using Ruby, how can I get a count for all positive numbers from a slice of an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am working on a, seemingly, simple Ruby application that I would eventually like to port to Rails. However I am getting stuck on understanding how, best, to slice the array so that I can evaluate the elements.

NOTE: I am not worried about golfing the code, but any suggestions or cleanup would be greatly appreciated :D

**In brief:**

I want to be able to shuffle an array, slice it into equal parts, count up the values greater than zero, and shuffle those counts.

Plaintext Example:

```
Set an array to (-2 -1 0 0 1 2)

Shuffle so that (0 2 -1 0 1 -2)

First slice (0 2)
    Count of values > 0 = 1

Second slice (-1 0)
    Count of values > 0 = 0

Third slice (1 -2)
    Count of values > 0 = 1

Array of counted values is now = (1 0 1)

Which are shuffled into (0 1 1)
```

**Long Version:**

Given an array of:

```
VALUES = %w(-5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5)
```

Shuffle those values:

```
rand = VALUES.shuffle
```

Then slice the array into 4 parts (each slice should have 4 elements)

```
rand.each_slice(4).to_a
```

Now I want to take each slice and count the number of values above zero.
However this is where I am getting stuck.

Namely, how do I pick slice1, slice2...sliceN?

I also tried to run with:

```
rand[0..3].select {|e| e > 0}.size
```

But that gives me an error (after commenting out the rand.each_slice(4).to_a)

```
ruby char_gen.rb 
char_gen.rb:18:in `>': comparison of String with 0 failed (ArgumentError)
    from char_gen.rb:18:in `block in <main>'
    from char_gen.rb:18:in `select'
    from char_gen.rb:18:in `<main>'
```

I think if I can get passed this I can figure out the rest, but the -FINAL- Step would be to build an array from the counted values and shuffle those as well...

Here is the full block of code that I am hacking away at.

```
    # Initialize some variables
    VALUES = %w(-5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5)

    # Shuffle skill values
    rand = VALUES.shuffle

    #rand.each_slice(4).to_a

    rand[0..3].select {|e| e > 0}.size

    #group2 = rand[4..7]
    #group3 = rand[8..11]
    #group4 = rand[12..15]

    #violence = group1.select {|e| e < 0}.count
    #charisma = group2.select {|e| e < 0}.count
    #intellegence = stat[2]
    #mechanics = stat[3]


    puts("
    -------------------
    Stats:
    -------------------
    Violence: #{violence}, Charisma: #{charisma}, Intellegence: #{intellegence}, Mechanics: #{mechanics}

    -------------------
    Skills:
    -------------------
    Athletics: #{rand[0]}   Guns: #{rand[4]}    Melee: #{rand[8]}   Throw: #{rand[12]}
    Science: #{rand[1]} Psychology: #{rand[5]}  Bureaucracy: #{rand[9]} Local\ Knowledge: #{rand[13]}
    Bluff: #{rand[2]}   Charm: #{rand[6]}   Intimidate: #{rand[10]} Stealth: #{rand[14]}
    Operate: #{rand[3]}     Engineer: #{rand[7]}    Program: #{rand[11]}    Demolitions: #{rand[15]}

    ")
```

Comment: Not sure what you desired output is but `VALUES.map(&:to_i).shuffle.each_slice(4).map{|a| a.count {|e| e > 0} }` will return an `Array` with a size of 4 of the elements counted as being greater than 0.

Comment: I'm curious – what is your algorithm supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Point about the ArgumentError is that `%w{1 2 3}` creates an array of Strings ('letters', which are unclear about how to behave when asked if greater than 0), not numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's more of a "code golf" answer:

```
VALUES = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

VALUES
  .shuffle                         # shuffle the array
  .each_slice(4)                   # split into equal* parts
  .map{ |s| s.count(&:positive?) } # count up the values greater than zero
  .shuffle                         # and shuffle those counts
```

*If your original array's length is not divisible by 4, then the last slice will be shorter than the rest.

Comment: Tom,  this is also a really slick answer but I'm not entirely sure how to get the outputs after the .shuffle steps ;-;

Comment: You didn't really specify which outputs you actually wanted ;)

Comment: Anyway, you can just perform these steps one at a time, and save variables along the way, if you wish. For example: `shuffled = VALUES.shuffle; sliced = shuffled.each_slice(4); ....`

Comment: Yeah... I guess I really only explained the -functional- parts that I wanted... d-oh...

The idea is to be able to grab the values so that I can assign them to other strings... i.e. character attributes for an RPG

Comment: I think I got what I was looking for with big props to everyone here :D

Answer (score 2):

`rand.each_slice(4).to_a` doens't convert the original array in slice. You need to assign it to a variable before you operate further.

```
VALUES = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
#=> [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

random_arr = VALUES.shuffle
#=> [2, 5, 4, -4, 0, 0, -1, 0, -5, 1, -3, 0, 0, -2, 0, 3]

slice = random_arr.each_slice(4)
#=> [[2, 5, 4, -4], [0, 0, -1, 0], [-5, 1, -3, 0], [0, -2, 0, 3]]

slice.map { |s| s.count{ |x| x > 0 } }
# => [3, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Why are you creating an array of strings, only to convert them back into integers? Just create an array of integers.

Comment: Good point. Made the changes. I was working on the existing steps taken by OP.

Comment: You are STILL creating an array of strings, only to covert them back into integers.

Comment: `[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` -- there.

Comment: Instead of `s.select{ |x| x > 0 }.count` you can use `s.count { |x| x > 0 }` or – in recent Ruby's – `s.count(&:positive?)`

Comment: @stefan, Tom: Thanks. Did the changes. :)

Comment: Just one minor nitpick: [`rand`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-rand) is also a global function, I'd use another name.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs guys! I've pretty much just been copy/paste/hacking at other bits of code that I've found on the net. Still working on learning Ruby properly ;)

Addendum... Would like to +1 this answer but I have 0 reputation -.-

Comment: There's no need for `.to_a`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Thanks. I should have been careful while crafting this answer. :D I used OP's existing steps and just highlighted where thing was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with. Big thanks for everyone inputs :D

```
VALUES = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

shuffled = VALUES.shuffle;

puts "The shuffled values are #{shuffled}"

sliced = shuffled
  .each_slice(4)
  .map{ |s| s.count(&:positive?) }
  .shuffle;

puts "The sliced values are #{sliced}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

arr.shuffle.map { |n| n>0 ? 1 : 0 }.each_slice(4).map { |a| a.reduce(:+) }
  #=> [1, 1, 0, 3]
```

From a probabilistic standpoint, shuffling the returned array serves no purpose.

Comment: Cary, thank you for commenting. 

The shuffle is more about pseudo-randomizing choices that would otherwise be made by a human. What I am doing is essentially making a quick-n-dirty way to assign values that have no human bias. Hence I'm not super worried about probabilities.

Comment: Your second shuffle is analogous to `arr.shuffle.shuffle` instead of `arr.shuffle`. If you compare the probability distributions of the returned values with and without a final `.shuffle`, you would find they are identical. That's why I say the final shuffle serves no purpose.